# On the table there's a pile of $n$ coins...

Tags: combinatorics

On the table there's a pile of $n$ coins. In every move you choose a pile of $a$ coins ($a> 1$) and seperate it into two piles of $b$ and $c$ ($b\ge 1,c\ge 1$, $a=b+c$) and write down their product $a\cdot b\cdot c$. You repeat these moves until there's $n$ piles on the table all of them with $1$ coin, after which you sum up all of the products written down. Determine, in terms of $n$, all of the sums you can get.

This is from an old Serbian problemset and it's a really puzzling question, there's so many edge cases to look for and I'm quite stumped as to where to start. Does anyone have any ideas they'd like to share? Thanks for reading!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Try specific small numbers first-n=1,2,3,4 and 5